# @Secured is not working while integrating Spring Security in Jersey project

Tags: spring-security, jersey

I have a demo JAX-RS project using Jersey. Now I am trying  add Spring Security's method level security but unfortunately its not working although `intercept-url` xml way is working fine.

1. Added all the dependency in my `pom.xml`
2. Updating `web.xml` as

   ```xml
   <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>
       /WEB-INF/security.xml,
       /WEB-INF/beans.xml
   </param-value>
   </context-param>
   <!-- this is default security impl name used by deletetingFiterProxy -->
   <filter>
       <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```
3. Updating `/WEB-INF/security.xml`

   ```xml
   <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
       <!-- kind of authentication applied 1) Basic 2) form-based etc.. auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"-->
       <http  auto-config="true">
           <http-basic />
       </http>

       <!-- this allow to enable security annotations in restful resoruces -->
       <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"  />

       <!-- for defining users and roles -->
       <authentication-manager>
           <authentication-provider>
               <user-service>
                   <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_CUSTOMER,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
                   <user name="student" password="student" authorities="ROLE_CUSTOMER"/>
               </user-service>
           </authentication-provider>
       </authentication-manager>
   </beans:beans>
   ```
4. Annotating service inteface methods

   ```java
   public interface StudentServiceInterface {

       @GET
       @Path("/students")
       @Secured("ROLE_CUSTOMER")
       public Response getStudents();

       @GET
       @Path("/students/{id}")
       @Secured("ROLE_CUSTOMER")
       public Response getStudent(@PathParam("id") int id);

       @POST
       @Path("/students")
       @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
       public Response addStudent(Student stu);
   }
   ```

Now when I try to access the resource student (`/student`) class it opens without asking password.

```
http://localhost:3126/securitydemo/webapi/db/students
```

**StudentServiceInterface interface implementation**

```java
@Path("/db")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class StudentService implements StudentServiceInterface{

    static StudentDao data= new StudentDaoImpl();

    @Override
    public Response getStudents(){
        GenericEntity<List<Student>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Student>>(data.getAllStudents()){};
        return  Response.ok(entity).build();
    }

    @Override
    public Response getStudent(@PathParam("id") int id){
        return  Response.ok(data.getStudent(id)).build();
    }


    @Override
    public Response addStudent(Student stu) {
        data.addStudent(stu);
        return Response.ok(stu).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Jersey verion 2.25.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the extention for Spring DI, see [Jersey 2.25.1 User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.25.1/spring.html):

> Jersey provides an extension to support Spring DI. This enables Jersey to use Spring beans as JAX-RS components (e.g. resources and providers) and also allows Spring to inject into Jersey managed components.
>
> The Spring extension module configuration is based on annotations. Spring beans are injected and JAX-RS classes are made Spring managed using annotations. Injected Spring beans can have further dependencies injected using Spring XML configuration. Spring singleton and request scopes are supported.
>
> To enable JAX-RS resources to work Spring functionality that requires proxying, such as Spring transaction management (with @Transactional), Spring Security and aspect oriented programming (such as @Aspect), the resources must themselves be managed by Spring, by annotating with @Component, @Service, @Controller or @Repository:
>
> ```java
> import javax.ws.rs.GET;
> import javax.ws.rs.Path;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
>
> @Component
> @Path("/")
> public class SomeResource {
>
>     @Transactional
>     @GET
>     public void updateResource() {
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Limitations:
>
> Spring beans can't be injected directly into JAX-RS classes by using Spring XML configuration
>
> **25.1. Dependencies**
>
> If you want to use Jersey Spring DI support you will need to add the jersey-spring3 module into the list of your dependencies:
>
> ```xml
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
>     <version>2.25.1</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> The above module adds transitive dependencies on Spring modules. See jersey-spring3 module dependencies for more details about list and scope of dependencies. Please note the module depends on The Spring/HK2 Bridge that is used to inject Spring services into HK2 services or inject HK2 services into Spring services.